# Google AdMob iOS - No Ads to Show

Tags: ios, swift, admob, app-store

I am facing this issue for very long time now.

1. Test Ads Appearing on Simulator and Actual Phone.
2. Implementation is Correct and Latest.
3. AdMob Account is approved, payment info added.
4. App is also live as well.

Still saying no `No Ads to Show`. Please help me on this.

Here is code functions

```
func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(bannerView)
    view.addConstraints(
        [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                            attribute: .bottom,
                            relatedBy: .equal,
                            toItem: bottomLayoutGuide,
                            attribute: .top,
                            multiplier: 1,
                            constant: 0),
         NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                            attribute: .centerX,
                            relatedBy: .equal,
                            toItem: view,
                            attribute: .centerX,
                            multiplier: 1,
                            constant: 0)
    ])
}
```

I Tried this as well instead of `adSize`

```
 let request = GADRequest()
    //request.testDevices = ["e217e5a45bc6b1042b5ea044243894c0" ]
```

//        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = [(kGADSimulatorID as! String)]

//        let bannerSize = UIDevice.current.isPad ? kGADAdSizeFullBanner : kGADAdSizeBanner

```
let adSize = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
                                            height: UIDevice.current.isPad ? 90 : 50))
    
    banner = GADBannerView(adSize: adSize)
    addBannerViewToView(banner)
    banner.adUnitID = AD_MOB_BANNER
    banner.rootViewController = self
    banner.delegate = self
    banner.load(request)
```

Comment: Are you trying this in simulator? If so, try this on a real device. Maybe you are in a region that currently does not have any ads available?

Comment: banners cannot have any size, they must have certain values... try ` bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)` instead your value (bounds.width)

Comment: @ExeRhythm I am trying with Actual Device. It's not showing it. My App is even live and not showing ads in any other countries too, because the impression in Admob is 0 nothing.

Comment: @TonyMkenu  I tried this. You can see my code that I tried that one too with condition that if iPad then `kGADAdSizeFullBanner ` otherwise `kGADAdSizeBanner `

Comment: @TonyMkenu can you please help me in this ?

Comment: I have the same problem:  no live ads for 5 days. It's a new (not released yet) iOS game -  test ads all work fine and I have other live apps in AdMob all working fine. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @Bbx nope. I am still having same issue. No Solution yet so far. Please let me know if you found any or need to discuss with me.

Comment: @SaadUllah yes, I found a solution. For me it was to release my game in the App Store (Disc Drop) - it still didn't get ads initially, but after 18 hours ads appearred. I answered my own question about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65237868/admob-on-ios-no-ad-to-show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was a Google Ads issue. My Code was correct and ads started appearing. It took time but ads started appearing.

Hope this helps. You can reach out to me if you are facing similar issue